# Como passar uma váriável em uma função JavaScript pelo onclick razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho uma série de campos que preciso enviar da `tag` `Razor` para uma função `JavaScript`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Enviar", "ActionName", null, new {
    onclick = String.Format("envia_pessoa({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}')", @item.ID, @item.Nome, @item.Endereco, @item.CEP, @item.Cidade, @item.UF)
});
```

Porém, não consigo enviar essas variáveis para a `função JavaScript`. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Erro:

> Índice (baseado em zero) deve ser maior ou igual a zero e menor que o tamanho da lista de argumentos.

Comment: Como ele ta gerando o HTML?

Comment: O código está dando o seguinte erro:  Índice (baseado em zero) deve ser maior ou igual a zero e menor que o tamanho da lista de argumentos. Na realidade eu supus que o código é implementado dessa forma.

Comment: Posta sua função javascript

Comment: Achei o problema, postei ali

Comment: Se possível marque a resposta como a resposta certa para auxiliar usuários posteriores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o erro, você está passando **7** parâmetros no `String.Format` e apenas **6** valores no final

Você tem que alterar

```
onclick = String.Format("envia_pessoa({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}')", @item.ID, @item.Nome, @item.Endereco, @item.CEP, @item.Cidade, @item.UF)
```

Para

```
onclick = String.Format("envia_pessoa({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')", @item.ID, @item.Nome, @item.Endereco, @item.CEP, @item.Cidade, @item.UF)
```

Dessa forma ficam ambos com 6 valores.

Comment: A minha tag html está voltando com o onclick na frente do href. Tenho um outro problema que está fazendo eu quebrar a cabeça:  Como faço para pegar o object routen value da página e enviar para o java script?

Comment: @GermanoSampaio o que exatamente você precisa?

Comment: O resultado da minha consulta deve retornar para outra página para campos correspondentes. para isso eu estou utilizando o javascript para colocar os campos retornados da consulta para os campos da tela principal. Isso pode ser fácil, mas sou novo em Razor e em JavaScript tb.
Abri um novo post com todo o problema:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67919/consulta-n-retorna-dados-para-partial-view-e-o-retorno-javascript-n%C3%A3o-retorna-os

Answer (score 0):

Na minha solução, tenho uma botão que abre uma modalview de consulta. Após a consulta, preciso retornar na mesma o resultado dos registros em forma de link. Ao clicar no link, devo retornar para a tela principal o resultado da consulta mas antes alterando e direcionando os campos para um ou mais que recebem a mesma referência. Estou tendo dois problemas: O primeiro é que eu n estou conseguindo retornar o resultado da consulta na PartialView Modal, e o segundo quando eu envio o retorno da consulta, na entra no metodo JavaScript que redireciona os campos. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue o código resumido: View de cadastro de Notas:

View de notas

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NOTA_NOM_DEV, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", value = "", size = "45", maxlength = "45", type = "hidden" } })

@Html.ActionLink("Fornecedor", "_ConPessoas", "Pessoas", new { id = 4 }, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-default" , id = '4'})

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Initialize numeric spinner input boxes
        //$(".numeric-spinner").spinedit();

        // Initalize modal dialog
        // attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
        // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        });

        // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
        $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
            $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });

        //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
        $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        });

        $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>

_Partial view de Consulta
@{ Layout = null; } @using PagedList.Mvc; @*@using SisCerinfo.Models;*@ @using (Html.BeginForm("_ConPessoas", "Notas", FormMethod.Get)) {  
Pesquisa de Pessoas
CPF/CNPJ: @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PES_DOCID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "14", size = "14" } })*@ ou Nome: @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PES_NM, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "50", size = "50" } })*@

@*@Html.ActionLink("Devedor ", "ViewConPes", "Notas", null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-success" })*@
@{ if (Model != null) { foreach (var item in Model) { @item.PES_NM @Html.ActionLink("Enviar", "CadNotas", null, new { onclick = String.Format("informa_pessoa({0}, '{1}', '{2}'", @item.PES_ID,'0','0')}) } } } } $(function () { $('#approve-btn').click(function () { $('#modal-container').modal('hide'); }); }); function informa_pessoa(pesid, sus_lim, sus_dt) { //var pessoa = document.forms[0].id var pessoa = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() //var pessoa = document.frm.TipoPesquisa.value; //var pessoa = document.frm.TipoPesquisa.value; if (pessoa == 4) { window.opener.document.frm.NOTA_NOM_DEV.value = trim(pesnm); window.opener.document.frm.NOTA_LIM.value = trim(sus_lim); window.opener.document.frm.NOTA_DT.value = trim(sus_dt); } window.close(); }
```